# What is the purpose of cross-validation if the model is thrown away each iteration

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, analytics, data-science, cross-validation

In cross validation, let's say k-fold, each iteration we basiclly create new model from scrach- we toss the previous scored model and create a new one based on a different training set.

as we all know- the strength of a model is the data it was trained on (besides of course the its hyper parameters).

so my question is- **what's the point of the scoring if the model is changing all the time?**

after the cross validation we don't take the mean the model values.. just calculating the mean of the scores of models that don't exist anymore.
I obviously miss something, but besides choosing the hyper-parameters and maby as in indication for the most suited model (from a very high level of perspective)- I don't see the benefit of the cross validation.

Answer (score 3):

You do cross-validation to get an estimate of how well your model will perform on unseen data. The point is to see how well it generalises.

Once you've done cross-validation and are happy with your score, you can re-train on your entire train set and then seeing how well it does on your test set. If your test set is from a similar distribution to your train set, and if you did cross-validation correctly, you should get a similar score.

The reason you can't just use the test set from the start is that you're only supposed to use the test set once - if you're unhappy with your test set score, you can't go back and retrain else you risk overfitting.

Comment: that's the part I don't undersatnd- each iteration the model that we get is a little bit different beacuse we use a different training set. maby the first model is performing great on unseen data (because of the specific trianing set it worked on) and the last is no.. so I would like to get the first one.
but the only thing we get from the CV process is an average score..


but now that I think of it again- maby I've took it the wrong way.. the point of the CV is not to get a TRUE score of the accuracy of the prediction model?

Answer (score 1):

Cross Validation is a very useful statistical method, It is commonly used in machine learning to compare and select a good model.

But you may miss, when you should use a cross validation? .

So what should I do in case of having two models which uses a different algorithm or some modifications on the features (Feature engineering) or any sensitive modification, and both perform the same on the test set.

Which one of these modifications is the best, (going to perform well on my application or in a real world case).

Usually we have a lot of models need to be compared.Cross Validation helps you to determine which one of these models you should use,because of the cross validation fit a model at a multiple scenarios (various test input).

i.e. if you are using k-fold cross validation, You now have (k) batches of the test set for measuring how well the performance of your model in each batch of the test set.